# propagate manually set types to redefine a function in IDA pro?

Tags: ida, idapython

Is there anyway in IDA pro to propagate manually set types of variables to redefine function arguments?

for example lets say IDA thinks Func1 takes 4 int as INPUT, now when i set the type of these 4 variables to something else, i have to again manually do this inside the function as well, and so on.. is there anyway to fix this? i tried reanalyzing but still they didnt propagate

Comment: It’s not clear at all what you are trying to do. Could you add some code snippets to the question?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky lets say i redefine variable v22 in function1 to a new_TYPE, now function1 calls function2 with v22, how can i redefine the definition of funciton2 as function2( new_TYPE a1) automatically? so i dont have to press Y on the function2 name and redifine manually?